# Is there any alternate for the app bar icon button circle in windows phone?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I found that all the app bar icon button has round layer, I know it is drawn by the App bar only; but my question is, can we make any other shapes like square or is there any alterations to do that.

[image]

can we able to draw any other shapes instead of that circle in the above image.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Windows 8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, you're stuck with the circle unless you roll-your-own `ApplicationBar`-lookalike.

Charles Petzold's [Programming Windows Phone 7](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/archive/2010/10/28/free-ebook-programming-windows-phone-7-by-charles-petzold.aspx) hints at this on pages 232-233:

> The actual image should be white and occupy a 26-pixels square area in the middle of the bitmap.

Whilst the icons in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v7.1\Icons\` have the circles around them, the circles are excluded by the '26-pixel square area', and are re-added by the `ApplicationBar`. Thus, the circles are unable to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you change this icon located in this directory

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v7.1\Icons\light\appbar.basecircle.rest.png
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v7.1\Icons\dark\appbar.basecircle.rest.png
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw people using regular rectangle-shaped buttons there but that was because they were not using the base app bar control. The app bar is not rendered by application and you have no control over the buttons other than specifying the icon and the label. You can use these regular rectangle-shaped buttons but I would not recommend it unless you have only 1..2 buttons, they always fit on screen and you don't need to use menu items.