# How to add normal buttons to Appbar in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, appbar

I am aware of app bar icons and menu items in Windows phone. What I want it is an app bar similar to phone's default windows phone store where it shows up "try", "buy" and share in menu item... How can I achieve this? I looked into [documentation of ApplicationBar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.shell.iapplicationbar%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), but it didn't help.

I want normal buttons to be inside application bar.. If that is not possible in appbar how can I mock something similar to the one which shows up in windows phone store..
[image: default app bar in windows phone store]

Answer (score 0):

[Not sure that it is possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14619566/is-there-any-alternate-for-the-app-bar-icon-button-circle-in-windows-phone)

Though, you may try to take a look at some custom appbars. For example, [Cimbalino appbar](http://www.pedrolamas.com/2013/03/11/cimbalino-windows-phone-toolkit-multiapplicationbarbehavior/) is made as behavior (so it supports binding) - probably, you'd be able to set button's style either.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. Then how is it coming in default windows phone store. They should be using something native right?

Comment: Probably I should paint that area in grey color and add buttons on top of it... well it works for Dark theme.. and something similar to Light theme..

Comment: I guess, you can name it as "native", because it was produced by MS. However, i think, it is not opened for users. For example, when you're reading mail, you can see "respond" button in appbar, and when you press it, appbar submenu appears (with lines "reply","reply all", "forward"). However, there's no possibility to use it for us: we need to make custom control if we want to have something looking the same.

Comment: Yep, i think, you should take a look at those custom appbars ( https://bindableapplicationb.codeplex.com/, https://github.com/kamranayub/CaliburnBindableAppBar, just google "wp7 bindable appbar" ) - probably, some of them would have their own buttons implementation, so you'd be able to override button's style.

Comment: Okay, here ( https://bindableapplicationb.codeplex.com/ ), there's "ButtonTemplate (used with ButtonsSource in a similar way ListBox.ItemTemplate is used with ListBox.ItemsSource)" - try that one.